# Adding 2 matrix and Multiplying 2 matrix in python by using scipy/numpy

Tags: python, math, matrix, numpy, scipy

I am trying to use scipy and numpy to perform matrix addition and multiplication.

I have 2 matrix "a" and "b". my goal is to add "a" and "b" together and store the result into a matrix "c"

Also I want to multiply "a" and "b" and store into a matrix "d".

Are there any function perform like that in Scipy/Numpy?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: numpy's `matrix` type does matrix multiplication, while the `array` type does pointwise multiplication, which do you want?

Comment: Is matrix multiplication like "dot product" when pointwise multiplcation is like every point multiply corresponding point?

Comment: Yes.  Check it out in a console and see for yourself.  If you could give me some example data and what result you expect I could tell you which operation you want.

Comment: I am doing image processing in python, a method called Pyramid Based Data Fusion Scheme. I have one question: Is there only one way to do addition of two matrix?

Comment: As far as I know there's only one way to add matrices.

Comment: What if I want to multiply every element in the matrix to a number "A"? should I write like: a = numpy.matrix(a),       b = A,       c= a*b ?

Comment: Multiplying by a constant is array multiplication rather than matrix multiplication, but you could do it by `a = numpy.matrix(a); b = A; c = a*b;`

Comment: Numpy for Matlab Users (http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users) has a nice summary of numpy ndarray and matrix operations.  element-wise operations, broadcasting, matrix operations, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Matrix multiplication:

```
a = numpy.matrix(a)
b = numpy.matrix(b)
c = a+b
d = a*b
```

Array multiplication (map operator.mul):

```
a = numpy.array(a)
b = numpy.array(b)
c = a+b
d = a*b
```